# Can anyone recommend some guided anapanasati resources on the Web?

Tags: theravada, reference-request, anapanasati, meditation

I'm trying to take my practice back to the beginning in the hopes of energizing it and I think this might be helpful.I currently don't have access to a teacher so some Web resources would be great particularly some guided mediations that I could follow.

Comment: Preferably turned into a community wiki

Answer (score 5):

The best is to go to directly to the Sutta or what the Buddha directly had to say about it. There are 2 good translations by Piya Tan:

1. [Anapanasati Sutta](http://www.themindingcentre.org/dharmafarer/wp-content/uploads/2009/12/7.13-Anapanasati-S-m118-piya.pdf)
2. [Anapanasati Sutta, Trilinear edition](http://www.themindingcentre.org/dharmafarer/wp-content/uploads/2010/12/m118-Anapanasati-S-v26-tlr-piya_2.pdf)

A more detail explanation of the Sutta is available in Mindfulness with Breathing: a Manual for Serious Beginners, 2nd edition which does a wonderful detailed explanations. (Don't use the 1st as this is a poor translation.) In addition there are some lectures by Budddhadasa Bikkhu: [Anapanasati by Ven. Buddhadasa](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=d8cVt2ClMSo).

For the very basics have a look at: [Mini Aanapana](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=K5CJLKTn47k).

Also

- [Anapana Sati Sutta](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UIGZcoKeeWI) by Bhante Vimalasiri
- [Anapana Sati Sutta](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HS0BaNYSv8U&list=PL0JQ276hWJUC7VG0gpXx34jEUYCoTR4N5) by Ven. Bikku Bodhi

would be helpful guides.

Also you can try to locate a more formal retreat like through: http://www.dhamma.org/en/index or http://www.buddhanet.info/wbd/ which will solve the issue that you do not have a teacher.

Answer (score 5):

I used to think that "guided" meditation was a superficial thing. Now I know that that view isn't very true...There are some very "not superficial" guided meditations out there that are made by some serious meditation teachers. Off the top of my head there is Gil Fronsdal's guided meditations(only "Anapana" was searched for...he has a ton of other guided meditations and talks.) 
   Joseph Goldstein, Ajahn Brahma, Thanissaro Bhikkhu, Jon Kabbat-Zinn and many others I didn't think of are all great at giving guided meditation like Anapana, Vipassana and Metta. To find more guided meditations(all these teachers do not charge money), you can google the teachers name in quotes plus "guided Anapana". Here is a bunch of guided Anapana by Gil Fronsdsal:

http://www.audiodharma.org/talks/?
search=Anapana

Answer (score 3):

also This book compiles  Buddhawajana (exclusively Buddha's words) regarding Anapanasati.  It's free.    [Buddhawajana anapanasati](http://15c78e68827edd100d00-3e5118b4a901d5cb5f2a37359b3bf3bc.r28.cf1.rackcdn.com/Anapanasati_English_version.pdf)